# GtkFileChooserDialog with image preview

Tags: python, gtk

How to create an image preview in a `GtkFileChooserDialog`?

Here is a simple ChooserDialog:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

filechooserdialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog()
filechooserdialog.set_title("FileChooserDialog")
filechooserdialog.add_button("_Open", Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
filechooserdialog.add_button("_Cancel", Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL)
filechooserdialog.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)

response = filechooserdialog.run()

if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
    print("File selected: %s" % filechooserdialog.get_filename())

filechooserdialog.destroy()
```

How to add a image preview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GtkFileChooser provides the [set_preview_widget](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-set-preview-widget) function. You create a GtkImage, set it as the preview widget, and update the image whenever the `update-preview` signal is emitted:

```
from gi.repository import GdkPixbuf

preview_image= Gtk.Image()
filechooserdialog.set_preview_widget(preview_image)

def update_preview(dialog):
    path= dialog.get_preview_filename()
    try:
        pixbuf= GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file(path)
    except Exception:
        dialog.set_preview_widget_active(False)
    else:
        #scale the image
        maxwidth, maxheight= 300.0, 700.0 # as floats to avoid integer division in python2
        width, height= pixbuf.get_width(), pixbuf.get_height()
        scale= min(maxwidth/width, maxheight/height)
        if scale<1:
            width, height= int(width*scale), int(height*scale)
            pixbuf= pixbuf.scale_simple(width, height, GdkPixbuf.InterpType.BILINEAR)

        preview_image.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
        dialog.set_preview_widget_active(True)
filechooserdialog.connect('update-preview', update_preview)
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay in return.
It works perfectly, but I'm looking for a way to handle exceptions more specifically, `except Exception` seems to be inadvisable. 
I was looking [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/GdkPixbuf-2.0/classes/Pixbuf.html#GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file) and [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/GdkPixbuf-2.0/enums.html#GdkPixbuf.PixbufError) but I not understand how to treat it with `try`/`except`.

Comment: Hi! The solution for my last comment is `from gi.repository.GLib import GError` and `Except (GError, TypeError):` or even more `except (GError, OSError, IOError, TypeError):`.
Thanks for your answer!